# Printed variable is undefined while resolving with Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a page that init with Loading a big object tournament:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.navbar.setLoading(true);
    this.tournamentService.getTournament(this.slug)
      .subscribe(tournament => {
        this.data = tournament;
        localStorage.setItem('tournament', JSON.stringify(tournament));
        this.navbar.setLoading(false);
      }, err => {
        this.navbar.setLoading(false);
      });
    this.navbar.setLoading(false);
  }
```

In my HTML, I have a lot of reference of tournament that will fails while data is not accesible. How should I do to avoid that?

I already tried using ? operator, but I don't like to put it everywhere, and it will fail when using in an expression like : `[(ngModel)]="data.tournament"`

I tried to disabled rendering based on a boolean `loading` with:

```
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="data">
```

but I get a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

so, how should I do it not to have those error while data is being loaded?

Comment: why do you have `this.navbar.setLoading(false);` at the end?

Comment: wrap ngInit code inside a timeout or Promise.resolve().then(...)

Comment: the last one is an error :)

Comment: nginit code is ok, it performs the query, but view access still undefined data

Comment: I am talking about using timeout etc to fix ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Comment: ok, but I heard it is not a good practice, isn't it ?

Comment: depends on your need... if experienced users have difficulty figuring out what is going on even with a redesign of work flow, I would go with async operation like timeout, more readable and maintainable for colleagues

Comment: @muuvmuuv >>> I already tried using ? operator, but I don't like to put it everywhere, and it will fail when using in an expression like : [(ngModel)]="data.tournament"

Comment: Try using router resolveres: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data